# Angular1.3: ng-bind-html not working when trying to load html elements/tags in a string?

Tags: angularjs, frontend, javascript-framework, angularjs-filter, angular-directive

I am trying to render some html tags in a string `example: ("<div>test</div><p></p>......")` pulled from some json data, but my usual $sce.trustAsHtml() filter below does not work for some reason and just renders the string as plain text:

myHtmlFilter.js :----

```
angular
  .module('myApp.htmlFilter', [])

  .filter('html', ['$sce', function ($sce) { 
    return function (text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
  }]);
```

index.html:----

```
<div ng-bind-html='View2.loadedJson.htmlTextString | html'></div>
```

It does seem to work if i just hardcode some html directly into the filter like below:

```
<div ng-bind-html='"<strong>Test</strong>" | html'></div>
```

would anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Any log errors? it seems to work properly, **[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/clNaJuAnWcCOBsazXXd6?p=preview)**

Comment: Have you add ngsanitize plugin?

Comment: The OP is already using **[`$sce.trustAsHtml()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml)**, I don't think adding **[`ngSantize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize)** would really the help with the problem at hand.

Comment: no errors logs either

Answer (score 0):

You need to include ngSanitize in your app.  From the docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml):

> To utilize this functionality, ensure that $sanitize is available, for example, by including ngSanitize in your module's dependencies (not in core Angular). In order to use ngSanitize in your module's dependencies, you need to include "angular-sanitize.js" in your application.

You need to change the first line in your script and make include a link to the angular sanitize js file in your html:

```
angular.module('myApp.htmlFilter', ['ngSanitize'])
```

Edit: http://plnkr.co/edit/LNblnXUIakoSuWHkIAeZ?p=preview

Comment: I have tried this, but it still only works with hardcoded strings, same as without

Comment: Did you try the plunker link?